# android library project manifest security setting in application project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I ran into one confusing issue today about the security tip on developer.android.com such as

1. [allowbackup](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#allowbackup)
2. [debuggable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug)

according to 
[this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) merging logic, **I think it will come to application manifest and then library manifest.** if now host app overwrite the flags i set in library, does that mean i no longer have protection to my library?

for example,

```
<manifest  //this is library manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
  package="com.MYLIBRARY_MANIFEST"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <application android:allowBackup="false" 
   android:label="@string/app_name">
  </application>
</manifest>


<manifest  //this is application manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
  package="com.MYAPPLICATION_MANIFEST"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <application android:allowBackup="true" //overwrite it as true
   android:label="@string/app_name">
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Is there a away to protect the library itself by forcing the library not allowbackup or not debuggable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does that mean i no longer have protection to my library?

Libraries do not really have "protection" in the first place with respect to manifest entries. Users do.

The developer of the app that uses your library can choose what to do for `android:allowBackup`, `android:debuggable`, etc. In the specific case of `android:debuggable`, that is usually set via Gradle: `debug` builds set it `true`; `release` builds set it `false`.

> Is there a away to protect the library itself by forcing the library not allowbackup or not debuggable?

Libraries do not really have "protection" in the first place with respect to manifest entries. Users do.

You cannot prevent developers from setting whatever value they want for those attributes.

You are welcome to examine the `ApplicationInfo` object for the app (call `getApplicationInfo()` on any `Context`) to see what those flags are set to. You are then welcome to take whatever steps you want based upon that information.

However, bear in mind that the step you appear to want to take — prevent the app from running if the developer does not submit to your demands — simply means that your library will not be used. Telling developers that they cannot do `debug` builds, for example, is not going to be very popular.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand the importance of  debug flag for application developers( not library devs) but how about allowsbackup flag? if we want to protect the data(file) generate by library in file system by not allowing backup, is that doable?

Comment: @Chi: No. The app developer makes the decision of what data gets backed up. If you do not want your data to be backed up, do not put the data on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You have Host project and Library. I will explain in debuggable example.

Actually host app always will be play a most important role.
If you doesn't include `debuggable` flag into manifest file in your library, Android get this flag in Host App (if exist).

So when you setup `debuggable = false` flag in Library and `debuggable=true` in Host App, this means that you `debuggable` flag doesn't affect library, but Host app - affected.